# How to select multiple JDK version in declarative pipeline Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to use different JDK versions for different stages in Jenkins declarative pipeline. In the first stage I am using Java 8. In the second stage i am using Java 6. How to select multiple JDK version in declarative pipeline in Jenkins?

```
  pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {
    jdk 'jdk_1.8.0_151'
    jdk 'jdk_1.6.0_45'
  }

  stages {
    stage('java 8') {
      steps {
        sh 'java -version'
        sh 'javac -version'
      }
    }
    stage('java 6') {
      steps {
        sh 'java -version'
        sh 'javac -version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can add a tools section for each stage.

```
pipeline {
        agent any

        stages {  
            stage ("first") {
                tools {
                   jdk "jdk-1.8.101"
                }
                steps {
                    sh 'java -version'
                }
            }
            stage("second"){
                tools {
                   jdk "jdk-1.8.152"
                }
                steps{
                    sh 'java -version'
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: can we use if statement in tools block?

Comment: don't think so , what are you trying to achive ?

Comment: because I want use 1 jenkinsfile for both java8 & java11 application. I have some jenkins job such as: **-java8-***, **-java11-***. So I pretend use JOB NAME to detect jdk version

Answer (score 11):

From the [Pipeline tools directive](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools):

```
tools: A section defining tools to auto-install and put on the PATH. 

The tool name must be pre-configured in Jenkins under 
Manage Jenkins → Global Tool Configuration.
```

From the [pipeline-examples](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/maven-and-jdk-specific-version/mavenAndJdkSpecificVersion.groovy) and [cloudbess example](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204421664-Select-which-Java-JDK-to-use-in-Pipeline):

```
  pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {
    jdk 'jdk_1.8.0_151'
  }

  stages {
    stage('jdk 8') {
      steps {
        sh 'java -version'
        sh 'javac -version'
      }
    }
    stage('jdk 6') {
      steps {
        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'openjdk_1.6.0_45'}", "PATH=${tool 'openjdk_1.6.0_45'}/bin:${env.PATH}"]) {
          sh 'java -version'
          sh 'javac -version'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('global jdk') {
      steps {
        sh 'java -version'
        sh 'javac -version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend you to use different docker images for each stage if you want to have different JDK versions. You can achieve using the docker hub openjdk images with the correct tag.
https://hub.docker.com/r/library/openjdk/

https://hub.docker.com/r/library/openjdk/tags/
Something like that:

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('openjdk:7-jdk') {
        agent {
            docker { image 'jdk7_image' }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'java -version'
        }
    }
    stage('java8') {
        agent {
            docker { image 'openjdk:8-jdk' }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'java -version'
        }
    }
}
```

}