# Specify JAVA_HOME in Jenkins for Java 11

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I have several projects running in Java 1.8 and Jenkins groovy script + Ansible acting as a pipleine to do deploys. 
Some of the projects are now migrated to Java 11 (OpenJDK). How do I configure Jenkins to build these projects in migrated to Java 11?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Jenkins 2.x, under Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Global Tool Configuration,
you should find a section "**JDK Installations**".

Configure multiple your jdk there. I'd not recommend "Install automatically" for Oracle JDK given their licensing changes since April 2019.

[image: JDK Installations]

This question describes handling [multiple jdk in a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895668/how-to-select-multiple-jdk-version-in-declarative-pipeline-jenkins).

Corresponding the names in the image example the tools values would be:

```
  tools {
    jdk 'jdk1.8'
    jdk 'jdk1.6'
  }
```

For maven,

Use a maven toolchain / profiles to be able to dynamically choose which to use: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html

ps: for freestyle jobs, the choice in in the General tab:
[image]

Note: if only one JDK is available, the [option is hidden](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10191).

Comment: Under Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > Under JDK Name I see only one option "Install automatically". Under this I see option "Add Installer" ("Extract *zip" "Run Batch/Shell command") In your post I see JAVA_HOME location given so did you install 1.8 already? I am stuck here, how to proceed further.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to add java 11 jdk by going to Manage Jenkins menu. This will fix the build issues.

For groovy script:
You cannot set JAVA_HOME in jenkins and expect maven to pick up correctly. It wont work. 
The successful approach was to add this in the pipeline:

```
env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'openjdk_11_0_1'}"
env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

"openjdk_11_0_1" beeing the name of the java configuration initially registered into Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global properties > Add environment variable.
[JAVA_HOME environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f15ol.png)