# Jenkins 2.365 with node having JDK8

Tags: jenkins, java-8, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, java-11

We have recently upgraded Jenkins 2.365 for which we are using openJDK-11.

But, we are still using JDK8 to build and execute the test, I want to attach the node of RHEL machine with JDK8

Won't it possible with latest Jenkins i.e. version 2.365 releases?

Comment: The agent has to launched using [Java 11](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/06/28/require-java-11/). Your solution is the inverse of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56843764/598141)

Comment: Humm. Okay, I'll attach agent using Java-11 and will use JDK-8 as per need in the Jobs. Thanks 

Comment: Feel free to upvote linked answer.