# Specify JAVA_HOME for maven job with java 8 and sonar scan with Java 11 in jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I need to run my maven build with java 8 and sonarscan with java 11, but not sure how to do it in same job.
When I am trying to build a job using java 8 in jenkins gui then sonar scan fails cz java 11 is missing to run and vise versa.
Can you please suggest how to provide JAVA_HOME for both explicitly and where do we add it exactly in jenkins.

Comment: You can use Java 11 to create a build targeting Java 8. There is no need to explicitly use Java 8 for this.

Comment: the code is failing cz of it, code is in java 8 and sonar scans are in java 11

Answer (score 0):

Setting multiple Java/JDK instances is very easy using a Jenkins build pipeline, which should be the preferred way over the pure GUI configuration.

For details see:
[How to select multiple JDK version in declarative pipeline Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895668/how-to-select-multiple-jdk-version-in-declarative-pipeline-jenkins)

Comment: we are using freestyle jobs, not sure where to add this explicitly.